# Filtering out table rows using row.names that are exact strings

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to subset my data based on the row.names column. My remove vector may have upwards of 30 titles in it. I'd like to remove entire rows of data from my set by using something that would work like this (although this, obviously, doesn't work). I can either modify the linear regression model, or just the original data set.

```
remove = -c("I Am A Movie", "I Am Also A Movie", "Avengers", "etc") 
IVOD = lm(IVOD, subset=remove)
```

My data looks like this, with 500+ rows and about 60 more columns.

```
    row.names       IVOD_REV_ULT    DBO    
1   I Am A Movie    1234567.91      1234670
2   Avengers        123456.99       1234567
```

How do I create a vector of strings, and remove only those rows that match, *exactly*, the row.names string? This worked with a vector of numbers, but for people repeating this process who may be less familiar with R than even me, I need them to be able to see the actual names of the films being removed to avoid any mistakes if the data is ordered differently. 
It is possible that some movies may have the same initial strings (ie "Dark Knight" and "Dark Knight Rises") so I also need my removal command to remove only perfect matches.

Thanks in advance -- apologies if this is easier than I think it is. I've been researching it for 2 days and can't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(row.names = c("apple", "banana", "orange", "lemon", "lime"), 
             value = c(1:5))
remove_these <- c("apple", "orange")
```

Now we find the indicies of the rows that need to be removed

```
rows_to_remove <- which(row.names(df) %in% remove_these)
```

And use the same technique you were trying to use before to remove rows.

```
df <- df[-rows_to_remove,]
```

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you. I'm pretty sure I follow what you're doing, but the %in% is something I haven't seen before. You essentially translated the titles to row numbers, created a row vector, and re-wrote the table sans the row vector. Thank you!!

Comment: Yep the %in% is super useful.  Glad this worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using data.table's subset function to perform this. Below is how I would do it using data.table.

```
  library (data.table)
  library (random)
  library (dplyr)

  #create a fake dataset with movie names and rating
  set.seed (5280)
  foo.data <- data.table (movie.name = as.character (randomStrings (n = 25, len = 2, digits = FALSE)), rating = as.integer (runif (n = 25, min = 0, max = 5)))

  #create a dataset of movie names to remove
  remove <- sample_n (foo.data, size = 10)

  #remove the movies using data.table subset
  new.foo.data <- subset (foo.data, !movie.name %in% remove$movie.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(states = state.name, region = state.region)
head(df)
#       states region
# 1    Alabama  South
# 2     Alaska   West
# 3    Arizona   West
# 4   Arkansas  South
# 5 California   West
# 6   Colorado   West

remove <- c("Arkansas|Florida")
grepl(remove, df$states)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [35] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

df[grepl(remove, df$states), ]

#     states region
# 4 Arkansas  South
# 9  Florida  South

df[!grepl(remove, df$states), ] # answer
# or subset(df, !grepl(remove, df$states))
```

At the end of the day utilize the pipe `|` operator within regular expressions in `grepl` or its variants (see `?grep`)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways.
First, here's a pretend dataset with a lot of rows.  This isn't your analysis, it's just to make a dataset that looks pretty much like yours.

```
movie.url <- "http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/ggplot2/movies.csv"
download.file(movie.url, "movies.csv")
movie.data <- read.csv("movies.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
row.names <- unique(movie.data$title)
IVOD_REV_ULT <- round(runif(n=length(row.names), min=123456, max=234567), digits=1)
DBO <- round(runif(n=length(row.names), min=123456, max=234567), digits=0)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(row.names, IVOD_REV_ULT, DBO))
df$IVOD_REV_ULT <- as.numeric(df$IVOD_REV_ULT)
```

Now we have something that matches the structure you pasted above.

It looks like you're trying to do a regression?  To do that, you need to put the dependent variable first, followed by a tilde, and then all the independent variables. If you use "subset", one way to do it is to use %in%. (Or in this case, negate it, so that it's not in.

### Do a regression with some movies removed.

```
remove <-  c("Princess Bride, The", "Avengers, The", "Fast and Furious") 
IVOD <- lm(IVOD_REV_ULT ~ DBO, data=df, subset=!row.names %in% remove)
```

I'd hesitate to use "grep" because it matches parts of strings.  So, for example, all the Fast and Furious sequels would be removed, rather than just the one I specified above.

Outside of a regression context, you can just explicitly remove them, like so:

```
subset <- df[!df$row.names %in% remove, ]
```

or...

```
subset <- df[-which(df$row.names %in% remove), ]
```

...although I think using "which" adds sort of an unnecessary step.

Comment: This is also really helpful -- by throwing the subset into the lm model, I can quickly tweak my data sets without changing the original data pull, if I'm looking at iterative attempts to create a better model (which I am!).

Comment: Is there a way to check off two different answers as being great? Both you and data paRty were really helpful.

Comment: Glad to help! You can upvote as many answers as you like, but I think you can accept just one. But no worries!

Comment: I'm getting a weird error. I'm sure that my title names exist in my data.frame. I ran it with only one title, and when I removed the subset argument, the error went away. What would cause this?
    Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
      'match' requires vector arguments

Comment: Jason O- I'm not sure what the problem is with your data.  I'd start by determining how it differs from the dataset I created above.  I'd start by making sure the data is a data frame, making sure that the columns are populated as I expect, and making sure that the type of the variable I'm subsetting on is what I'm treating it as (e.g. character, numeric).  To diagnose a problem specific to your data, I'd need access to your data.